# Only static members can be accessed in initializer. Dart2.0

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-2

I am using banklist in stateful widget. passing list to `pageState` using  `List<Bank> bankLists = this.widget.bankLists;`

**Que 1.** Why I am getting error at `gradientcolor: gradientBankCard("FFB74093","FFB74093"))` that  only static members can be accessed in initializer?

**Que 2.** How to pass const Data to `gradientBankCard` method . for Example I want to pass `Color.fromRGBO(220, 132, 58, 1.0)` to Arguments that gives error to.
I

```
List<Bank> bankLists = [
 Bank(
    id: "1",
    name: "B1",
    loanAmount: "₹ 250000",
    emi: "₹11732",
    intrest_rate: "11.69 % ",
    processing_fee: "1.29 %",
    tenure: "2 years",
    gradientcolor: gradientBankCard('#e48634', '#e48634')), // //Error : Only static members can be accessed in initializers
 Bank(
    id: "2",
    name: "B2",
    loanAmount: "₹ 250000",
    emi: "₹11732",
    intrest_rate: "11.69 % ",
    processing_fee: "1.29 %",
    tenure: "2 years",
    gradientcolor: gradientBankCard('#e48634', '#e48634')) //Error : Only static members can be accessed in initializers
];
```

Now I am using in my  listing screen .

```
LinearGradient gradientBankCard(String startColor, String  endColor){

return LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    colors: [Color(hexToInt(startColor)),Color(hexToInt(endColor))]
);
}
```

Bank Model.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class Bank {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String loanAmount;
  final String emi;
  final String intrest_rate;
  final String processing_fee;
  final String tenure;
  LinearGradient gradientcolor;

  Bank({this.id, this.name, this.loanAmount, this.emi, this.intrest_rate,
      this.processing_fee, this.tenure,this.gradientcolor});

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code

```
gradientcolor: gradientBankCard('#e48634', '#e48634')),
```

is executed before the class is fully initialized.
Initializers of fields like

```
List<Bank> bankLists = [...];
```

is executed before the super constructors are executed and at that point explicit or implict access to `this.` is not allowed because it would allow access to incompletely initialized state.

If you change

```
LinearGradient gradientBankCard(String startColor, String  endColor){ ...
```

to

```
static LinearGradient gradientBankCard(String startColor, String  endColor){
```

then there is no way to access `this.` and is therefore safe.

Comment: SO in this case i have to use static for that?  And if i want to create or typed any widget before creating body container . How to do that?

Comment: You can move the initialization to the constructor body, there it's already allowed to reference `this.`. If you want to make the field `final` it's more complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much.